# Node.js - Recursive function over process.stdin.on makes unwanted repetative behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I'm still a beginner in Node.js. So I'll have to post the entire function for an overall view:

I have this function 'loopDialog' which takes an object and a starting index. It starts a dialog that allows the user to

1. provide the names of required libraries for the project dependencies (by entering them comma separated and pressing enter).
2. to pass to the next dependency (by entering 'n' and pressing enter).
3. to exit (by entering 'e' and pressing enter)(which passes him to the next function).

My problem is, since I want the flow to be asynchronous, I tried looping by making it a recursive function. But, pressing (n) in the dialog (which passes the user to the next dependency) displays the messages "Do you know the system libraries..." for the same dependency by n times where n is the number of times I pressed 'n'.

The variable 'flag' is used to overcome another undesired behavior that makes the function continue to send post requests whenever the user enters anything even after the function is being exited.

For some reason I'm failing to solve this using async/await.

Is there any other way to avoid all this headache (or at least to fix the 'n' problem) ?

```
var request = require('request');
var qs1 = require('qs');

var oss = process.platform;

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var flag = true;
var res = {'unrecognized': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'dependencies': ['x', 'y', 'z']};

loopDialog (res, 0);

var loopDialog = function (res, i) {

    console.log(`Do you know the system libraries needed for: '${res.unrecognized[i]}' ?\n\n`);
    process.stdin.on('data', function(answer) {
        if (!flag) return;
        answer = answer.replace(/ /g, "").replace(/\n/g, "").split(",");

        if (answer.length === 0 || answer.length === 1 && answer[0].toLowerCase() === 'e'){
            flag = false;
            checkWhatToInstall(res.dependencies, 0);
        } else {
            if (answer.length === 1 && answer[0].toLowerCase() === 'n') {
                if ( i < res.unrecognized.length -1) {
                    loopDialog (res, ++i);
                }
                else{
                    flag = false;
                    checkWhatToInstall(res.dependencies, 0);
                }
            } else if (i < res.length){
                console.log(answer);
                var x = {form: {packages: res.unrecognized[i], os: oss, pack_type: 'npm', dependencies: answer}};
                request.post('http://localhost:3000/add', {
                    form: qs1.stringify({
                        package: res.unrecognized[i], os: oss, pack_type: 'npm', dependencies: answer
                    }, {
                        arrayFormat : 'brackets'
                    })}, 
                    function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            res.dependencies.concat(answer);
                            if (i < res.unrecognized.length -1)
                                loopDialog (res, ++i);
                            else {
                                flag = false;
                                checkWhatToInstall (res.dependencies, 0);
                            }
                        }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

var checkWhatToInstall (res, i) {
    console.log('Do something');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up initializing a global array 'temp', whenever a member of res.unrecognized is used, it is pushed to 'temp' and then get evaluated the condition in the first line in the function, so that

```
....
var temp = [];
var loopDialog = function (res, i) {
    if (!flag || temp.includes(res.unrecognized[i])) return;
    console.log(`Do you know the system libraries needed for: '${res.unrecognized[i]}' ?\n\n`);
    temp.push(res.unrecognized[i]);
   ...
}
....
```

Note: I'm still looking for a better approach.